# Using InfoPath form for custom content type (derived from Task)

Tags: infopath, custom-form, tasks

I have Task library in which consists of several custom content types (all of them derived from Tasks content type.) For each custom content type I need to create form in InfoPath. How to assign those forms to content types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From InfoPath Designer

- Select File menu tab
- Select SharePoint List template
- Select Design Form button
- Enter Site URL
- Select existing List
- Select Content Type

The new InfoPath Form is now associated with a specific Content Type.

https://kerdirks.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/associate-custom-infopath-form-with-list-content-type/